# C++ Passing in a value from one class to an abstract class

Tags: c++, class, oop, inheritance, abstract-class

Let's say i want to create a quiz program. i have an abstract class Question and a subclass of it named QuestionMC.Then i have Class player which will obtain player information such as player name and filename(for fstream) from the user. How do i pass the information from class player (filename and playername) to class Question ?

```
class Question
{
    public:
        virtual void showQuestion()=0;
    protected:
        string filename;
        string question;
        string answer;
        string questionType;
};




class Player
    {
        public:
            Player(int score=0):score(score){}
            void askdetails();
            string getfilename();
            string filename;
        protected:
            string fname;
            string lname;

    };

class QuestionMC:public Question
{
    public:
        void showQuestion();
        void setfilename();


    protected:
        string mcQuestion;
        string mcfilename;  
};

int main()
{

    Player p;
    p.askdetails();
    p.getfilename();

    QuestionMC mc;
    mc.setfilename(p.filename);
}

void Player::askdetails()
{
    string filename,fname,lname;
    cout << "Please enter your First name : ";
    cin >> fname;
    cout << "Please enter your last name : " ;
    cin >> lname;
    cout << "Please enter the filename your quiz is stored : " ;
    cin >> filename;
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open(filename.c_str());

    if (infile.fail())
    {
        cout << "Error Opening file, either file does not exist or invalid filename "<<endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    this->fname=fname;
    this->lname=lname;
    this->filename=filename;

    ofstream outfile;
    outfile.open("Score.txt");
    outfile << "Player name and score : " << fname <<" "<< lname << " "<< score<<endl ;
    outfile.close();

}

string Player::getfilename()
{
    return filename;
}
void QuestionMC::setfilename(filename)
{
    mcfilename=filename;
}
```

Comment: Please take a look at the [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). Scott Meyers' are particularly interesting ones.

Comment: You may be able to access a parent classes data members directly, depending on the access settings of the parent variables and the inheritance access.

Comment: No you see i want to pass value from a class(which does not inherit) to a another class

Answer (score 0):

as long as class `QuestionMC` is derived from class `Question` all the `public` and `protected` members of `Question` are inherited in `QuestionMC`.

to set `filename` of class `Question` then set it as a member of `QuestionMC` so add this to your

```
void QuestionMC::setfilename(filename)
{
    this->filename = filename;
    mcfilename = filename;
}
```

it works but one question: what is the purpose of inheritance? as long as member `filename` in base class why you declare it again in derived class??

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this would be to create a third class that stored the pointer to everything you use-
In your case, it would store:

A pointer to the class Player.

A pointer to the class Question, or if it is created afterwards, to a vector that holds the pointers of all the questions.

Then, you add that class' pointer as a member to both of those classes (Player and Question), which will give them access to eachother.

This class would be a global variable, and should never be deleted until the end of the program (otherwise whenever trying to access to other classes it would crash).